# Nilpotency order of a maximal ideal $M$ of a finite local ring $(R,M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need an argument for the following assertion.

If $(R, M)$ is a local ring of order $p^k$ for some prime integer $p$, then $M^{k}=0$. In particular,  nilpotency order of $M$ is $<$ the order of $R$.

Comment: What is the question you have about your problem? Surely you aren't just asking for the answer (or are you?)  There is a very obvious conjecture one would make about the behavior of the powers of $M$ that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Somehow, the proof I have in mind of this fact seems to be an overkill, using Krull's intersection lemma.

Comment: @rschwieb  First of all, I thank you for your valuable comment.
 Of course, I am not looking for an answer only. I have a feeling It can be done with a simple argument, but I couldn't get it at that time. Now I think I got it, I will post it in the answer box in a few minutes. Kindly I need your review or amendment on it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we may assume that $R\neq 0$ and $R$ is not a field. Consider the chain $M^k\subseteq M^{k-1}\subseteq \ldots \subseteq M^2\subseteq M$. If $M^i=M^j$ for some $1\leq i<j\leq k$, then $M^i=0$ and hence in particular, all greater powers of $M$ are zero, by Nakayama lemma. So, assume that the above chain is strict, that is, $M^k\subset M^{k-1}\subset \ldots \subset M^2\subset M$. Therefore order of all $M^i$'s are disncit $k$ numbers $\leq p^{k-1}$ and all of them divides $p^k$. Thus, order of $M^k$ must be equal to $1$, as desired.

Note that, if the order of $R$ is $p^k$, then the nilpotency order of $M$ is $\leq k$.